How to reolsve "Don't use `object` type error" in React
I am getting this error for the code below. What is the correct type to use here in react?
src\withRouter.tsx
Line 18:38:  Don't use object as a type. The object type is currently hard to use (see this issue).
Consider using Record<string, unknown> instead, as it allows you to more easily inspect and use the keys  @typescript-eslint/ban-types
import { ComponentType } from "react";
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export interface WithRouterProps<T = ReturnType<typeof useParams>> {
    history: {
        back: () => void;
        goBack: () => void;
        location: ReturnType<typeof useLocation>;
        push: (url: string, state?: any) => void;
    };
    location: ReturnType<typeof useLocation>;
    match: {
        params: T;
    };
    navigate: ReturnType<typeof useNavigate>;
}

export const withRouter = <P extends object>(Component: ComponentType<P>) => {
    return (props: Omit<P, keyof WithRouterProps>) => {
        const location = useLocation();
        const match = { params: useParams() };
        const navigate = useNavigate();

        const history = {
            back: () => navigate(-1),
            goBack: () => navigate(-1),
            location,
            push: (url: string, state?: any) => navigate(url, { state }),
            replace: (url: string, state?: any) =>
                navigate(url, {
                    replace: true,
                    state,
                }),
        };

        return (
            <Component
                history={history}
                location={location}
                match={match}
                navigate={navigate}
                {...(props as P)}
            />
        );
    };
};


The error tells you what type to use. <P extends Record<string, unknown>> (instead of <P extends object>) is a more strict typing you can use for objects that have dynamic keys and values.

it does not work here, shows compile time errors
